# Webpack is looking for react in global directory

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Here's my webpack-dev-server configuations

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './main.js',
  output: {
    path: './',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    inline: true,
    port: 9000
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: '/(node_modules)/',
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        presets: ['es2015', 'react']
      }
    }]
  }
};
```

Why would I get the following error when I run the server

> ERROR in (webpack)-dev-server/~/strip-ansi/index.js
>   Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "react" relative to directory "/Users/ecco/.nvm/versions/node/v5.4.0/lib/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/strip-ansi"

my package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
"babel-core": "^6.4.5",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.2",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
"webpack": "^1.12.13"
}
```

Comment: try do the following steps. 1. `rm -rf node_modules` 2. `npm cache clean` 3. `npm i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't appear to have the `webpack-dev-server` installed as a local node module (it's not in your `package.json`

You can see which modules are installed locally and globally with `npm list` and `npm list --global`. To look for specific modules, pipe that command into `grep` i.e. `npm list --global | grep webpack-dev-server`

I'd suggest installing the dev server as a devDependency of your project. As a general rule, try to avoid installing modules with `-g` unless absolutely necessary. Also, use `npm` scripts (in your package.json) to run modules in your local directory, without having to reference them explicitly e.g.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "webpack-dev-server --config your.config.js"
  }
}
```

then run `npm run serve` rather than running `./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --config your.config.js` (or worse, installing it globally)